# In OpenSSH DEBUG1 output on connecting, what does the number in the `Server accepts key` line refer to?

Tags: ssh

When I connect to remote systems, specifically in this case using OpenSSH 6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u2, if I use the `-v` switch to see what's going on one of the lines printed is:

```
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 567
```

This looks to me like the server has accepted the identification public key (which is mentioned as offered on the immediately preceding line), which is great.

However, **what does the 567 at the end refer to?** "blen" sounds like it could be "bit length", but 567 isn't related to any bit length that I know of, even if converting bits to bytes.

Google was distinctly unhelpful, most likely because this stanza appears in more or less every `ssh -v somewhere.example.com` output that anyone has ever posted, but at least shows that the number varies (149, 277 and 279 are all on Google's first page of hits, when restricting to ssh-rsa exchanges).

Answer (score 0):

The blen indicates the signature bytelength followed by it values.

So in this case your public/private key was generated `4012` bit long thus you will have value of `567` of the signature.

Comment: How did you derive the number 4012 bits (which, according to my calculator, is 501.5 bytes) from 567 bytes? The specific key pair was generated as `ssh-keygen -b 4352 -t rsa` and 4352÷8 = 544 bytes of modulus.